# How to programmatically trigger a specific jenkins build managed via github-organization?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline

I am using the github-organization plugin to manage jenkins jobs from github but I discovered that Jenkins API does not report these builds.

In fact the API list the entire organization as a single job.

How can I build a specific repository and branch using the API?

To be clear, I am looking for some groovy code to add inside the `Jenkinsfile`

```
#!groovy

stage 'test-downstream'
node {
    def job = build job: 'some-job'
}
```

Now, the problem is that Jenkins is seeing the entire organization as a single job!

If I use Jenkins API to retrieve the jobs, it will return only the organization, and not all the repositories and jobs inside it.

I suspect that's because the way this plugin was implemented and I suppose that I need to give some extra parameters in order to specify which repository and branch I want to build inside the organization.... building an organization does not make much sense.

Comment: Can you clarify, are you using this [github-organization-folder-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/github-organization-folder-plugin) and want to manually trigger one of those jobs created by a Jenkinsfile? Also, have you tried if it works to trigger it via [url](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API) with the jobname from an already created job? Then youll just need to find out about the job-naming convention with that Jenkinsfile Pipeline stuff.

Comment: Sadly I tried using `acme/job/foo/job/master` as the job name but got `No parameterized job named acme/job/foo/job/master found` which tells me that probably it does not expose these as real jobs.

Comment: Check what is exposed on `http://<jenkinsserver>:<its port>/api/xml`

Comment: But yeah, its probably similar to how matrix-jobs work. One job and all combinations are just builds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is vague, but I am guessing “API” in this context means the REST API to trigger builds. You can use for example

```
curl -X POST -u user:apitoken http://jenkins/job/yourorg/job/yourrepo/job/master/build
```

Comment: While this is not really ideal it may work if I am unable to find a groovy. Still I hate having to deal with the API token issue from here when the Jenkinsfile execution was supposed to already have access to Jenkins api.

Comment: Then perhaps you are asking something totally different, and this is simply a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36306883/how-can-i-trigger-another-job-from-a-jenkins-pipeline-jenkinsfile

Answer (score 1):

The following code trigger job via System Groovy build step. Please note that system groovy always run on master so passing info from previous build steps might be tricky.

```
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.model.*
import java.util.concurrent.*

def run_job(job_name) {
  def currentBuild = Thread.currentThread().executable
  def jenkins = jenkins.model.Jenkins.getInstance();

  def job = jenkins.getItemByFullName(job_name);
  if (job == null)
      throw new hudson.AbortException("Cannot find job:" + job_name);

  def params =[
    new StringParameterValue('PARAMETER1', "invoke 1 param1"), 
    new StringParameterValue('PARAMETER2', ",invoke 1 param2")
  ]

  def paramsAction = new ParametersAction(params) 
  def cause = new hudson.model.Cause.UpstreamCause(currentBuild)
  def causeAction = new hudson.model.CauseAction(cause)     

  def future_build = job.scheduleBuild2(0,causeAction,paramsAction);
  def running_build = future_build.waitForStart()
  return running_build
}

run_job("runner1")
```