# Jenkins groovy pipeline - calling build step for another pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

### edit:

according to Andrew Bayer you're not supposed to inject declarative pipelines in to others. Support might come for it in the future but not might not come at all.

---

I'm currently trying to start a pipeline within a pipeline but I'm wondering what I need to do to make it work. The documentation on the jenkins webpage says that if the new job or pipeline is in the same folder as the first one you can call it from either direct name or absolute path. I've tried all different ways, currently I'm trying absolute path to a file I just checked exists one second earlier but it says that it doesn't exist.

I wonder what the correct way to link different pipelines together are.

```
steps {
    echo "hello ${env.WORKSPACE}"
    sh "ls ${env.WORKSPACE}"
    sh "ls ${env.WORKSPACE}/jenkins"
    build(job: "${env.WORKSPACE}/jenkins/css-core-pipeline", parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'param1', value: "$pass1" ]])
  }
```

> [Pipeline] echo
>
> hello /home/jenkins/workspace/hellopipeline
>
> [Pipeline] sh
>
> [hellopipeline] Running shell script
>
> .+ ls /home/jenkins/workspace/hellopipeline
>
> README.md
>
> .
>
> .
>
> .
>
> jenkins
>
> [Pipeline] sh
>
> [hellopipeline] Running shell script
>
> .+ ls /home/jenkins/workspace/hellopipeline/jenkins
>
> css-ce-pipeline
>
> css-core-pipeline
>
> css-dev-pipeline
>
> css-prod-pipeline
>
> manual.md
>
> .
>
> .
>
> .
>
> ERROR: No item named /home/jenkins/workspace/hellopipeline/jenkins/css-core-pipeline found
>
> Finished: FAILURE

Comment: I think what you're looking for is FrankIJ's answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36306883/how-can-i-trigger-another-job-from-a-jenkins-pipeline-jenkinsfile-with-github

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I trigger another job from a jenkins pipeline (jenkinsfile) with GitHub Org Plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36306883/how-can-i-trigger-another-job-from-a-jenkins-pipeline-jenkinsfile-with-github)

Comment: The problem is that i'm using a declarative pipeline, you're linking things for groovy pipelines

Answer (score 6):

The jobname without any prefix should be enough.

```
build(job: "css-core-pipeline", parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'param1', value: "$pass1" ]])
```

You can use the snippet generator to get a valid step snippet, if this doesn't work. Open the pipeline configuration -> Pipeline Syntax -> Snippet Generator -> Select build step -> Fill fields (there will be an autocomplete for the job name)

Answer (score 5):

What worked for me was that I was not scaping slashes properly, so I had to replace `jobname/feature/my-branch-name` like so:

```
        stage('Calls another pipeline') {
            steps {
                build job: 'jobname/feature%2Fmy-branch-name', parameters: [
                    string(name: 'MY_VAR', value: 'my_value')
                ],  propagate: true, wait: true

            }
        }
```