# Jenkins script that returns a pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Is it possible to create a pipeline inside a groovy script via a function call?

If I have a script such as:

```
def call() {
  pipeline {
    agent any
    stages { ... }
  }
}
```

then I can call this script in Jenkins with:

```
@Library('foo') _

foo()
```

And I see the pipeline running with all of its stages.

But if I change the script so that the pipeline step is outside of the call() method and in its own method:

```
def build() {
  pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

And call it via Jenkins:

```
@Library('foo') _

foo.build()
```

then I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'agent' found among steps [...]
```

I'd really like to have the one script with build(), deploy(), release(), etc methods, each defining their own pipeline, but it seems that a pipeline can only be created via the call() method, and I'll need to have separate scripts for each pipeline (build.groovy, deploy.groovy, etc).

Comment: You could build a job from a running job, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36306883/how-can-i-trigger-another-job-from-a-jenkins-pipeline-jenkinsfile-with-github).