# Multi-package Python project release pipeline

Tags: python, jenkins, build, pipeline, nexus

I have 3 projects (Git) which translates into 3 different Python packages.
Each package has it's own life cycle which I already facilitated (e.g. Build -> Lint -> Unit test -> Integration tests -> Push to Nexus), However, my problem is that I fail to understand how to create a pipeline for coupled projects.

So an example:
Project1 **relays on** project2 **which relays on** project3

If I a code is submitted to project 1, I would like to trigger a flow that bumps versions and aligns the project build at the end of the road.

How can I do it? Where can I find reference to what I'm looking for.

-- edit --

The question mainly asks how to manage a CI pipeline in terms of package versioning, git branches and release candidate. I'm into understanding the architecture of such pipeline.

Comment: You might be looking for **Pipeline: Build Step**  (https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/) in conjunction with **Build Pipeline plugin** (https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-pipeline-plugin). Also, see this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36306883/how-can-i-trigger-another-job-from-a-jenkins-pipeline-jenkinsfile-with-github.

Comment: Hi, I am familiar with the build steps and utilize it. I'm more into understanding how to manage and bump versions in both git perspective and dependencies. I'll edit my question so it will be clearer. thank you!