# How to add job build params in Jenkins shared Library?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl, jenkins-cli

This works

> steps.build "Job Name"

This doesn't work

> steps.build "Job Name -p ParamKey1=ParamValue1 -p ParamKey2=ParamValue2"

I also tried this but no luck

> steps.build "Job Name", parameters:[string(name: "Key1", value:"Value1")]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See the [documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/) for the supported parameters, and [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36306883/how-can-i-trigger-another-job-from-a-jenkins-pipeline-jenkinsfile-with-github) for examples.

Answer (score 0):

This is my example on passing parameters to the child job:

```
stage('Deploy PROD') {
    steps {
      build job: 'PROD/Great-Project-Prod',
            propagate: true,
            wait: true,
            parameters: [
              //static parameter
              string(name: 'environment', value: 'prod'),
              //parameter from a function defined on top of the file
              string(name: 'projectVersion', value: getVersion()),
              //parameter coming from UI defined parameters
              string(name: 'envFileId', value: params.envFileId)
            ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code accesses steps through the `steps` object: `steps.build`. The `string` method used in the `parameters` block has the same visibility as `build`. It means you have to use the `steps` object to access it:

```
steps.build "Job Name", parameters: [
    steps.string(name: "Key1", value:"Value1")
]
```